# How to save id from another model using choicefield?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-database

I have a ModelMultipleChoicefield and a queryset with another model.

`NamesModel` contains only `names` and `id`

`ID_model` contains only `id` of `NamesModel`

```
class MyCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_id = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=NamesModel.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = ID_model
```

When rendering form I can choose names for example. 'Adam', John'.

My problem is I want my form to display `NamesModel`, but save `NamesModel id` to `my_id`.

How can I do that?

Comment: That code should do exactly what you want. What's wrong with it?

Comment: `TypeError: expected ID_model instance, got <Person: 'Adam'>`. That's why I need to save id.

Comment: You're going to need to show your models. I can't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Because I'm getting `NameModel` from another database. `NameModel` got `id` and I need it to be save in `ID_model`